# Preventing eventClick trigger when drag and dropping events using angular-calendar

Tags: angular, events, angular-calendar

I have an issue with the current binding of (eventClicked) and (eventTimesChanged) using angular calendar when my events are both draggable and clickable.

NOTE: This behavior seems to happen on Firefox v84.0.2 but not on Chrome v87.0.4280.88

Dragging an event from one time slot to another sometimes triggers eventTimesChanged **AND** eventClicked when only the first one would have been expected.

This situation happens:

- On view *DAY*, everytime
- On view *WEEK*, if you drag an event onto the
  same day

Using  [this stackblitz sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-duwfrr?file=demo%2Fcomponent.ts) and by following the scenariis below, you can understand the behavior:

- On view WEEK, click on the event. The console outputs the eventClicked as expected
- On view WEEK, drag the event from one day to another. The console outputs the eventTimesChanged as expected
- On view WEEK, drag the event from one day to itself (by placing it on another time slot of the same day). The console outputs the eventTimesChanged as expected, **but also an unwanted eventClicked**
- On view DAY, click on the event. The console outputs the eventClicked as expected
- On view DAY, drag the event on another time slot. The console outputs the eventTimesChanged as expected, **but also an unwanted eventClicked**

Is there any way to block this eventClicked trigger after a drag and drop on the same day ? I feel like the event detection considers that a mouse click down + mouse click up on one event the same day will always be considered as a click, even if the time slot of the event when clicking down the mouse is different from the time slot of the event when the mouse click is released.

I feel like adding a kind of "delay detection" between the mouse click and the mouse release to define whether it should be considered as a click or a "hold then release" of the event should be sufficient as a workaround, but I don't know how to put it together in that way.

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the workaround I came up with. Not sure about its performances but it is working: Modify the component having the angular calendar doing these 3 points

1. Add a BehaviorSubject eventHasChangedSubject to track whether an event has been dragged and dropped recently
2. Start your (eventTimesChanged) binded method by pushing true into this subject, and push false in a 1ms timeout at the end of your action
3. Encapsulate the current content of your (eventClicked) binded method whithin a if (!this.eventHasChangedSubject.value)

```
export class MyClassContainingCalendarBindedMethods {

  private eventHasChangedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  eventTimesChanged(event: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
    this.eventHasChangedSubject.next(true);
    yourCurrentEventTimesChangedCode();
    setTimeout(() => this.eventHasChangedSubject.next(false), 1);
  }
  
  eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
    if (!this.eventHasChangedSubject.value) {
      yourCurrentEventClickedCode();
    }
  }

}
```